# How to take out the last character of a string every time it is printed using nested loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

So I just learned about nested loops in my class and we've been given a program and I can't seem to figure to out. The program prompts the user to enter a word and the output should print out the word how many times the number of the letter there is in a different line, and the last character of the word should be deleted every time the word is printed.

This is what I've got right now. I could only get it to print out the whole word and how many times it should print.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner kbreader = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = kbreader.nextLine();


        for ( int k = word.length(); k > 0; k--)
        {

            for (int m = 0; m <= word.length()-1; m++)
            {
                System.out.print(word.charAt(m));
            }

            System.out.println();          
        }       
    }
}
```

The program should print something out like this:

Enter a word: hello

> hello
>
> hell
>
> hel
>
> he
>
> h

but my program print out this:

> hello
>
> hello
>
> hello
>
> hello

Answer (score 0):

The substring function is what you are looking for. It is found in (probably) every programming language.

Here is a working example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Also importantly if you use a negative number for the parameters it will substring from the 'end' of the string instead of the front, or it will count backwards instead of forwards.

You have a counter in your loop, so you should be easily able to have a play and get it working with this funciton.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
int length = word.length();
IntStream.range(0, length).forEach(i -> System.out.println(word.substring(0, length - i)));
```

Or

```
IntStream.range(0, length).mapToObj(i -> word.substring(0, length - i)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

It uses java `stream` and very concise.

Answer (score 0):

You just made one little mistake. You will probably notice that you did not use the `k` for anything, hence you were just doing the same task `k` times. Just change `m <= word.length()-1` to `m < word.length()-k`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner kbreader = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    String word = kbreader.nextLine();


    for ( int k = word.length(); k > 0; k--)
    {

        for (int m = 0; m < word.length()-k; m++)
        {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(m));
        }

        System.out.println();          
       }       
   }
 }
```